# myArray.map is not a function: Trying to set React state with data from Javascript Fetch API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, express, fetch

I am trying to set React state with data from a Postgres database using Javascript's Fetch api. I am confused on a lot of aspects so trying to piece it together.

First, set the initial state...

```
let initialClients = [
  {id: 1, firstName: 'Juicy', lastName: 'J'},
  {id: 2, firstName: 'Big', lastName: 'pimpin'},
  {id: 3, firstName: 'Snoop', lastName: 'Dogg'},
];

export default function TestCustomers(){

  const [Clients, setClients] = useState(initialClients);
```

Okay, that works. From now on I use setClients() to set the new state.

Because promises don't actually give me the value, or.. an ability to set a value for use outside of the promise, I guess I'm supposed to try and use await. To do that I'm supposed to use an async function? Fine. Here's my attempt (almost full set of code):

```
export default function TestCustomers(){

  const [Clients, setClients] = useState(initialClients);
  const ref = useRef(false);
  let testData;

  async function setClientsAsync(){

    const response = await fetch('/api/clients');
    const myJson = await response.json();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
//    setClients(JSON.stringify(myJson));
//    return JSON.stringify(myJson);

  }

  if (!ref.current) {
    setClientsAsync();

    ref.current = true;
  }
```

the `console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));`  returns the CORRECT array of objects that SHOULD be able to go directly into the `setClients();`  ... but when I try to uncomment the `setClients(JSON.stringify(myJson));` line, I get this error:  **Clients.map is not a function.**

Why? It doesn't seem like I'm passing in a promise. I don't know where to even begin or know what the problem is related to.

The `console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));` returns this:

```
[{"id":1,"firstName":"first1","lastName":"last1"},{"id":2,"firstName":"first2","lastName":"las2"},{"id":3,"firstName":"first3","lastName":"last3"}]
```

The Return function:

```
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => {getNewClients()}}>Get New Clients</button>
      <h2>Clients....</h2>
      <ul>
        {Clients.map(client =>
                     <li key={client.id}>{client.firstName} {client.lastName}</li>
                    )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: JSON.stringify(myJson) will return a string of myJson, don't do a stringify to keep it as an object.. ex: setClients(myJson);

Comment: Glen K you are my hero.

Comment: I'd probably also use useEffect hook to make an API call